# c# BitmapImage AccessViolationException when saving as MemoryStream

Tags: c#, bitmap, system.drawing, bitmapimage

I'm trying to save a BitmapImage (System.Windows.Media.Imaging) via a memorystream so that the result can be used to create a Bitmap (System.Drawing).

I intermittently get an error when trying to save the encoded result to a memorystream:

```
An exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

The properties of the memorystream seem to indicate that a read or write timeout has occurred.

```
WriteTimeout = 'msOut.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

Code below, the error is thrown at the Save command:

```
         System.Windows.Media.Imaging.CroppedBitmap cbi = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.CroppedBitmap(bi, new System.Windows.Int32Rect(
            (int)(imageViewBox[2] * imageViewBox[10]), (int)(imageViewBox[3] * imageViewBox[11]), 
            (int)((imageViewBox[4] - imageViewBox[2]) * imageViewBox[10]), (int)((imageViewBox[5] - imageViewBox[3]) * imageViewBox[11])));
        newImageSize = new Size(cbi.PixelWidth, cbi.PixelHeight);

        using (MemoryStream msOut = new MemoryStream())
        {
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BmpBitmapEncoder enc = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BmpBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(cbi));
            // Throws access violation exception when zoomed on some images. Why?
            enc.Save(msOut);
            using (Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(msOut))
            { ...
```

The images in question are generally 1000px x 500 so not massive.
Any ideas what could be causing this? Or any ideas how else I could do the conversion without using a memorystream (without degrading performance?)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the original source bitmapimage for the croppedbitmap (not shown in above code) was causing the issue.

This bitmapimage was loaded from disk via a URI. I've found that setting the BitmapCacheOption to `Onload` instead of `None` removes the error. I'm guessing the image was not fully loaded at the point of conversion. However, it reduces performance about threefold, which is unfortunate.